# Why doesn't the full-glyphicons set work with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I needed the Skype glyphicon in my Bootstrap 3 project.

I found this nice repo on github:
https://github.com/ericzhang-cn/full-glyphicons

I copied in the folder img the two images, imported the CSS file `glyphicons.css` and tried to use an icon as explained in github:

```
<i class="icon-g-skype"></i> Address roma
```

But is not working.
Has anyone else had this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Twitter Bootstrap 3, the icon class is replaced with `glyphicon`.

So you can use like `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>`.

For better icons check http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Thank you! It's quite amazing! Is not working with me including the css files in the project but only with the links netdna, but the important is that is working!

Answer (score 1):

You can include Font-Awesome via CDN in your HEAD:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

(Check [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for the latest URL in case this becomes outdated.)

Then where you want the Skype icon:

```
<span class="fa fa-skype"></span>
```

Comment: A minified version of the CSS file is also available on bootstrapcdn - //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css